# How to pass C++ callback as a click handler of a Button in android?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I am building an android app and I need to create UI elements dynamically from JNI part and assign C++ functions as click handler.

I have defined a java function to create a button and return it.
I have a C++ function that calls the Java function and has jobject of button. Now I want to assign another C++ function as click handler to this object.

Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    public View control(String text) {
        Button bt = new Button(this);
        bt.setText(text);
        ((ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_main)).addView(bt);
        return bt;
    }
}
```

C++:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_shaidin_ebellum_MainActivity_start(JNIEnv *env, jobject me)
{
    jmethodID jControl = env->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(me), "control", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/view/View;");
    jstring jText = env->NewStringUTF("test");
    jobject jView = env->CallObjectMethod(me, jControl, jText);

    // How to add listener here?

    env->DeleteLocalRef(jView_);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(jText);
}
```

In this question
[Android UI in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227086/android-ui-in-c/6305497)
JNIpp library
https://github.com/DmitrySkiba/itoa-jnipp
has introduced and it does exactly what I want, but I want to implement it myself because I don't want to add that much code to my project. Also that library has a complicated implementation using nested macros that makes it difficult to learn how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of making a Java object do a callback to C++ code is pretty much always the same; make the Java object store some kind of reference to the native object (typically a pointer), and have it pass that pointer back to the C++ code which can call the appropriate function.

A potential implementation could look like this:

**MyOnClickListener.java**

```
public class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final long nativePeer;

    public MyOnClickListener(final long nativePeer) {
        this.nativePeer = nativePeer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        OnClick(nativePeer);
    }

    @Override
    public void finalize() {
        Release(nativePeer);
    }

    private static native void OnClick(final long peer);
    private static native void Release(final long peer);
}
```

**C++**

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void Java_com_example_myapp_MyOnClickListener_OnClick(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jclass clazz,
        jlong nativePeer) {
    auto f = reinterpret_cast<std::function<void(void)>*>(nativePeer);
    (*f)();
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void Java_com_example_myapp_MyOnClickListener_Release(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jclass clazz,
        jlong nativePeer) {
    auto f = reinterpret_cast<std::function<void(void)>*>(nativePeer);
    delete f;
}

...

// Setting the OnClickListener

// We allocate this object with `new` since we need it to remain alive
// until the Java code no longer needs it. It is the responsibility of
// the Java code to ensure that the memory gets freed.
auto callback = new std::function<void(void)>([] {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "MyOnClickListener", "Hello from native onClick!");
});

jclass listener_clazz = env->FindClass("com/example/myapp/MyOnClickListener");
jmethodID new_listener = env->GetMethodID(listener_clazz, "<init>", "(J)V");
jobject listener = env->NewObject(listener_clazz, new_listener, callback);

jmethodID set_onclicklistener = env->GetMethodID(button_clazz, "setOnClickListener", "(Landroid/view/View$OnClickListener;)V");

env->CallVoidMethod(button, set_onclicklistener, listener);
```

---

**Note 1:** In your real code you should of course add proper error handling and not blindly assume that every JNI call succeeds.

**Note 2:** Rather than relying on `finalize` to be called you might want to explicitly invoke the `Release` function when you no longer need the native peer object.

**Note 3:** I used a pointer to a `std::function` in my example. You may want to use a pointer to some class of your own. That's really up to you to decide.